# Ubuntu 13.10 adb "device not found"

Tags: linux, adb

I'm trying to reinstall Android on my first-gen Nexus 7. I'm using `adb` to do so because the install is so corrupted I can't even use the touch screen.

I use Ubuntu 13.10 and I have `adb` and `fastboot` installed. My Nexus is plugged in. This is what I type:

```
sudo adb kill-server
sudo adb start-server
adb devices
```

And... nothing shows up. How do I fix this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15844160/nexus-7-tablet-not-recognized-by-adb

Comment: @caffinatedmonkey Did not work.

Comment: Please post the output of `lsusb` when your device is plugged in.

Comment: You need add info about you device to 'adb_usb.ini'
Solved here [http://askubuntu.com/questions/213874/how-to-configure-adb-access-for-android-devices][1]


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/213874/how-to-configure-adb-access-for-android-devices

Answer (score 1):

Try running "sudo adb devices". Or, fix your udev rules so that the USB device is writable by your user (see the link in caffinatedmonkey's comment)

Comment: I've tried `sudo adb devices`. Thanks for the advice tho!

Answer (score -3):

Use PTP option instead of MTP USB PC Connection.

Comment: How did you end up with this conclusion? Please explain and possibly back it up with source(s) too.